# Google Places Api details is no longer showing reviews?

Tags: google-places-api

I have been running google places api to get a locations reviews that has been successfully working about 8 months now. I'm now getting place details that are missing the reviews. The documentation mentions:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

This gives me the json as it always has. `json['result']['reviews']` has given 5 reviews for the location. However the reviews are no longer showing. So I'm getting a nil error. Does anyone understand why this could be happening?

Comment: It looks like this is ongoing issue on Google side and it was reported in Google issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79874130

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't reproduce this bug on my side. Your request returns 5 reviews for me.

Comment: The request works for a single call on one business but if I run multiple queries to get reviews from multiple places then it fails after 1 but before others.

Comment: Google marked bug 79874130 as Fixed.